# rename all files in folder through regular expression

Tags: linux, bash, file-rename, batch-rename

I have a folder with lots of files which name has the following structure:

```
01.artist_name - song_name.mp3
```

I want to go through all of them and rename them using the regexp:

```
/^d+\./
```

so i get only :

```
artist_name - song_name.mp3
```

How can i do this in bash?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in BASH:

```
for f in [0-9]*.mp3; do
   mv "$f" "${f#*.}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Perl `rename` utility](http://search.cpan.org/~rmbarker/File-Rename-0.06/rename.PL) utility. It might be installed on your version of Linux or easy to find.

```
rename 's/^\d+\.//' -n *.mp3
```

With the `-n` flag, it will be a *dry run*, printing what would be renamed, without actually renaming. If the output looks good, drop the `-n` flag.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'sed' bash command to do so:

```
for f in *.mp3; 
do 
    new_name="$(echo $f | sed 's/[^.]*.//')"
    mv $f $new_name
done
```

...in this case, regular expression *[^.]*.*  matches everything before first period of a string.